# saving images to resources folder in iphone

Tags: iphone

i am downloading images from the server i would like to know whether it is possible to save those images to the resources folder of the project...if it is possible please someone explain me.
Thank you

Comment: by resources folder, you mean the resources folder you see in Xcode? 
that's not an actual folder, it's just a way to group your assets together. What you are looking for is how to save the images to the iPhone's filesystem, am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do that but resource folder is call **Document Directory** in iPhone and you can save anything that you want and almost all abstract data types have a method to do that name `writeToFileAtPath:atomically:`. // note atomically, not automatically`

You just need to pass the path of file where you want to save it.

As far as path of **Document Directory** is concerned its like this

```
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
```

this returns the path of **Document Directory**

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
             NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
             NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MD%d.png",y]];
             UIImage *image = imgProfile; // imgProfile is the image which you are fetching from url
             NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
             [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
```